# Ошибка Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Как решить?

Tags: php, json, opencart

Выдает ошибку при оформлении заказа без регистрации.

> **Notice**: Undefined index: firstname in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **244****Notice**: Undefined index: lastname in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **248****Notice**: Undefined index: email in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **252****Notice**: Undefined index: email in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **252****Notice**: Undefined index: telephone in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **256****Notice**: Undefined index: address_1 in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **260****Notice**: Undefined index: city in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **264****Notice**: Undefined index: country_id in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **270****Notice**: Undefined index: country_id in
>   **/home/buffalob/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php**
>   on line **276**{"error":{"firstname":"\u0418\u043c\u044f
>   \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u043e \u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c
>   \u043e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 32
>   \u0441\u0438\u043c\u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432!","lastname":"\u0424\u0430\u043c\u0438\u043b\u0438\u044f
>   \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u0430 \u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c
>   \u043e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 32
>   \u0441\u0438\u043c\u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432!"}}

```html
<?php
class ControllerCheckoutGuest extends Controller {
 public function index() {
  $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');

  $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
  $data['text_none'] = $this->language->get('text_none');
  $data['text_your_details'] = $this->language->get('text_your_details');
  $data['text_your_account'] = $this->language->get('text_your_account');
  $data['text_your_address'] = $this->language->get('text_your_address');
  $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');

  $data['entry_firstname'] = $this->language->get('entry_firstname');
  $data['entry_lastname'] = $this->language->get('entry_lastname');
  $data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
  $data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
  $data['entry_fax'] = $this->language->get('entry_fax');
  $data['entry_company'] = $this->language->get('entry_company');
  $data['entry_customer_group'] = $this->language->get('entry_customer_group');
  $data['entry_address_1'] = $this->language->get('entry_address_1');
  $data['entry_address_2'] = $this->language->get('entry_address_2');
  $data['entry_postcode'] = $this->language->get('entry_postcode');
  $data['entry_city'] = $this->language->get('entry_city');
  $data['entry_country'] = $this->language->get('entry_country');
  $data['entry_zone'] = $this->language->get('entry_zone');
  $data['entry_shipping'] = $this->language->get('entry_shipping');

  $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
  $data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');

  $data['customer_groups'] = array();

  if (is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
   $this->load->model('account/customer_group');

   $customer_groups = $this->model_account_customer_group->getCustomerGroups();

   foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) {
    if (in_array($customer_group['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
     $data['customer_groups'][] = $customer_group;
    }
   }
  }

  
  if (isset($this->request->post['customer_group_id'])) {
   $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->request->post['customer_group_id'];
  } elseif(isset($this->session->data['guest']['customer_group_id'])) {

            
   $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->session->data['guest']['customer_group_id'];
  } else {
   $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
  }


//lightshop start
  $data['button_back'] = $this->language->get('button_back');
  $data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
  $data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
  $data['checkout_st3_sa'] = $this->config->get('theme_lightshop_checkout_st3_sa');
  
  $this->load->model('catalog/lightshop');
  $activeFields = $this->model_catalog_lightshop->getFields($data['customer_group_id']);
  $allFields = $this->model_catalog_lightshop->getAllFields();

  $data['allCustomFields'] = $allFields;
  foreach($allFields as $field){
   $data['entry_'.$field.'_required'] = 0;
   $data['entry_'.$field.'_show'] = 0;
  
   if (isset($this->request->post[$field])) {
    $data[$field] = $this->request->post[$field];
   } elseif (!empty($customer_info)) {
    $data[$field] = $customer_info[$field];
   } else {
    $data[$field] = '';
   }

   if (isset($this->error[$field])) {
    $data['error_'.$field] = $this->error[$field];
   } else {
    $data['error_'.$field] = '';
   }

  }

  foreach($activeFields as $field){
   if($field['description']){
    $data['entry_'.$field['name']] = $field['description'];
   }
   $data['entry_'.$field['name'].'_required'] = $field['required'];
   $data['entry_'.$field['name'].'_show'] = $field['is_show'];
  }


//lightshop end  

            
  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['firstname'])) {
   $data['firstname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['firstname'];
  } else {
   $data['firstname'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['lastname'])) {
   $data['lastname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['lastname'];
  } else {
   $data['lastname'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['email'])) {
   $data['email'] = $this->session->data['guest']['email'];
  } else {
   $data['email'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['telephone'])) {
   $data['telephone'] = $this->session->data['guest']['telephone'];
  } else {
   $data['telephone'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['fax'])) {
   $data['fax'] = $this->session->data['guest']['fax'];
  } else {
   $data['fax'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['company'])) {
   $data['company'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['company'];
  } else {
   $data['company'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['address_1'])) {
   $data['address_1'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['address_1'];
  } else {
   $data['address_1'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['address_2'])) {
   $data['address_2'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['address_2'];
  } else {
   $data['address_2'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['postcode'])) {
   $data['postcode'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['postcode'];
  } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['postcode'])) {
   $data['postcode'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['postcode'];
  } else {
   $data['postcode'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['city'])) {
   $data['city'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['city'];
  } else {
   $data['city'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['country_id'])) {
   $data['country_id'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['country_id'];
  } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'])) {
   $data['country_id'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'];
  } else {
   $data['country_id'] = $this->config->get('config_country_id');
  }

  if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['zone_id'])) {
   $data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['zone_id'];
  } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id'])) {
   $data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id'];
  } else {
   $data['zone_id'] = '';
  }

  $this->load->model('localisation/country');

  $data['countries'] = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountries();

  // Custom Fields
  $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

  $data['custom_fields'] = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields();

  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['custom_field'])) {
   if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['custom_field'])) {
    $guest_custom_field = $this->session->data['guest']['custom_field'];
   } else {
    $guest_custom_field = array();
   }

   if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['custom_field'])) {
    $address_custom_field = $this->session->data['payment_address']['custom_field'];
   } else {
    $address_custom_field = array();
   }

   $data['guest_custom_field'] = $guest_custom_field + $address_custom_field;
  } else {
   $data['guest_custom_field'] = array();
  }

  $data['shipping_required'] = $this->cart->hasShipping();

  if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['shipping_address'])) {
   $data['shipping_address'] = $this->session->data['guest']['shipping_address'];
  } else {
   $data['shipping_address'] = true;
  }

  // Captcha
  if ($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('guest', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
   $data['captcha'] = $this->load->controller('extension/captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha'));
  } else {
   $data['captcha'] = '';
  }

  $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/guest', $data));
 }

 public function save() {
  $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');

  $json = array();

  // Validate if customer is logged in.
  if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
   $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
  }

  // Validate cart has products and has stock.
  if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
   $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
  }

  // Check if guest checkout is available.
  if (!$this->config->get('config_checkout_guest') || $this->config->get('config_customer_price') || $this->cart->hasDownload()) {
   $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
  }

  if (!$json) {
 244 строка----------------  if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) > 32)) {
    $json['error']['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка    `Undefined index: .... in ...` в opencart говорит о том, что во время сабмита данных значения этих полей (firstname etc) не передались в контроллер. Либо передались не так, как он их ожидает.

Почему - тайна, покрытая полумраком. Обычно появляется после вмешательства в контроллер/шаблон. Сказать конкретнее не возможно, мало вводных.

Дебажте/приньте/эхайте/вардампье/дайте, и будет вах счастье.